# Make new strong password [ Kick Start 2022 Round C ]

Tags: python

Here is the question : https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/00000000008cb4d1/0000000000b20f15

And my solution :

```
no_of_tests = input()
for i in range(int(no_of_tests)):
    chars = int(input())
    s = input()
    if (any(x.isupper() for x in s) and any(x.islower() for x in s) and any(x.isdigit() for x in s) and any(x in ['#','@','*','&'] for x in s) and len(s) >= 7):
            # password satisfies all conditions 
            print(s)
    else:
            if not (any(x.isupper() for x in s)):
                s = s + 'A'
            if not (any(x.islower() for x in s)):
                s = s + 'a'
            if not (any(x.isdigit() for x in s)):
                s = s + '0'
            if not any(x in ['#','@','*','&'] for x in s):
                s = s + '*'
            if not len(s) >=7:
                s = s.rjust(7,'0')
            print(s)
```

I know that this isn't the best answer based on time complexity but can anyone tell me the logical issue in the above solution .

Comment: I think you can give up the satisfying test and use only the 'else' part. If there is nothing to fix, it saves you all the conditions check you do before.

Comment: Yeah . It will save time but will still fail test cases

Comment: For a reason that I don't understand, s is an empty string if there is no prompt for the input.

Comment: Yes , in case of empty string 000Aa0* will be the output